# Negative Volume

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to calculate the volume of the part of the paraboloid $z = 2-x^2-y^2$ contained in the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ $\color{blue}{\text{oriented in the upward direction}}$ (not sure if the blue part matters).

The purpose is to calculate the flux integral integral $\iint_S \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{S}$. where $\textbf{F} = <\tan\sqrt{z} + \sin{y^3}, e^{-x^2},z>$. It's $\nabla \cdot F = 1$.

This is the integral I calculated for the volume for the part of the paraboloid between $z = 2$ and $z= 1$:

$$\int^{2\pi}_0\int^0_1\int^{2-r^2}_1rdzdrd\theta = -\pi$$

I think it's correct to let $r$ goes from $1$ to $0$ because that corresponds with the $z$ value as it goes from $1$ to $2-r^2$.

The volume of this model obviously can't be negative, how is my logic false?

Comment: No. The integral is from $0$ to $1$ for $r$, and $z$ goes from $1$ to $2-r^2$

Comment: Don't forget to also add the volume of the cone up to $z=1$. That's still inside the paraboloid